# css3 flex: How to create 2 columns with : 100% + fixed width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a simple flex layout:

```css
#header {
  background-color: grey;
}
#container {
  display:flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
#chatAndUserContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;
}
#usersContainer {
  background-color: green;
  width:320px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="chatAndUserContainer">
    <div id="chatContainer">
      chatContainer
    </div>
    <div id="usersContainer">
      usersContainer
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is : when rendered, **the width of  #usersContainer  is not 320px but... 274px !**

Any idea on how to correct that ? (I need to use display:flex, not absolute)

Comment: that is GREAT. Could you just explain me why that works ?

Answer (score 4):

You are facing the **shrink** effect. Since the total width (100% + 320px) is bigger than 100% both your elements will shrink equally to fit their parent container.

To avoid this you can disable the shrink for the second div:

```css
#header {
  background-color: grey;
}
#container {
  display:flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
#chatAndUserContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;
}
#usersContainer {
  background-color: green;
  width:320px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="chatAndUserContainer">
    <div id="chatContainer">
      chatContainer
    </div>
    <div id="usersContainer">
      usersContainer
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Or don't use `width:100%` and replace it with `flex:1` so that your first div will fill the remaining space left by the second one:

```css
#header {
  background-color: grey;
}
#container {
  display:flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
#chatAndUserContainer {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}
#chatContainer {
  background-color: red;
    flex:1;
}
#usersContainer {
  background-color: green;
  width:320px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="chatAndUserContainer">
    <div id="chatContainer">
      chatContainer
    </div>
    <div id="usersContainer">
      usersContainer
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice modern solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc()` in `#chatContainer`, or `min-width` in `#usersContainer`, or use them both like in example below.

```css
#header {
  background-color: grey;
}
#container {
  display:flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
#chatAndUserContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width:calc(100% - 320px);
}
#usersContainer {
  background-color: green;
  width:320px;
  min-width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="chatAndUserContainer">
    <div id="chatContainer">
      chatContainer
    </div>
    <div id="usersContainer">
      usersContainer
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```